# How to Set PublishUrl of ClickOnce Application From CommandLine

Tags: deployment, command-line, msbuild, clickonce

I am working on a ClickOnce application. I am trying to publish it from command line using this:

```
msbuild Project.csproj /t:Publish /p:configuration=release;
```

The problem is I want to set some other properties along with configuration, like 'PublishUrl' etc.

I've tried this:

```
msbuild Project.csproj /t:Publish /p:configuration=release;publishurl="\\sdmm\publish\"
```

It builds successfully but the output of that project will be copied to the debug folder of application in app.publish folder.

How should I handle this thing? Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could set any property you want from the command line but before doing so, you need to open your .csproj file in some texteditor(notepad etc). Find the property that you want to edit. In your case it is publish url. Remove this property from csproj file.

Then you could do this

```
msbuild /target:clean,publish /p:publishurl=c:\publish_location\
```

you must clean the project before you publish it.

Answer (score 7):

Try to change your target to

> msbuild  /target:clean,rebuild,publish

because property you are overriding (PublishUrl) was not embedded into application file if only "Publish" target is used.

Comment: Thanks a lot, without your explanation of clean/rebuild I wouldn't notice it in another answer and would continue banging my head.

Comment: I read the answers but thought I knew better. It wasn't until I read your explanation that I understood why I needed to clean first to override the property.